# Adding new action for another model inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have Models `campaign` & `Publisher`.

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publisher

class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
```

In my `campaigns#_form` partial, when I am adding a `campaign`, I need to associate/select a `publisher`:

*My campaigns#_form:*

```
= simple_form_for(@campaign) do |f|
  = f.association :publisher
  // ... Other parts of the form
```

Currently, when I am adding a `campaign` I need to, first go to `publishers#new` and a new `publisher`, then come back to my `campaigns#_form` and create the `campaign` and associate/select a `publisher`.

I often forget to add the `publisher` first before adding the `campaign` and it has causes some issues.

Is it possible to be able to add a `publisher` in my `campaigns#_form` *(if I don't already have added the publisher)* without needing to add `publisher` first before creating the `campaign`.

If possible how to *select* this new `publisher` from: `= f.association :publisher`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying convey here.

> I often forget to add the publisher first before adding the campaign and it has causes some issues.

If you are structuring your application in the way you have mentioned above, You should add a publisher first, then only you should create campaign for that publisher because `campaign belongs_to a publisher`.

You should create you application flow in such a way that a campaign can't be created without associating it to a publisher.

Comment: There is many publishers already added in the application. Lets say that I already have **Publisher-1**, **Publisher-2**, **Publisher-3**. When I want to add a new `campaign` I already have those `publishers`, But I want to add `campaign` for **Publisher-4** that is not already added. Thats the ones that make issue, not the `publisher` that are already added and can be selected.

Comment: Then, in that case you should strict users to add a campaign to already exists publishers only. For eg: while creating a campaign, you can give a dropdown consisting of all the existing publishers and make it mandatory